# Не могу корректно сформировать сообщение telegram в сниппете WPforms WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram

Я новичок в написании сниппетов WordPress. Стандартный функционал плагина WPForms отправляет результаты формы на почту. Я захотел изменить функционал конкретной формы, что бы сообщение отправлялись не на почту, а в телеграмм через бота.
Вот мой код:

```
function wpf_dev_process_complete( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {
  
$bot_token = ""; // токен бота
$chat_id = ""; // ID чата
$id_form = 21; // Айди формы

// Проверяем айди нашей формы
if ( absint( $form_data[ 'id' ] ) != $id_form){
    return;
}
 
// Получаем весь объект
$entry = wpforms()->entry->get( $entry_id );

// Преобразуем поля в массив
$entry_fields = json_decode( $entry->fields, true );

$txt = "Новая заявка! %0A";

foreach ( $entry_fields as $id => $field ) {
    // Если поле пустое, то пропускаем его
    if(empty($field['value']))
        continue;
    // Заменяем разделители "__" на перенос строки
    strtr ($field['value'], array ('__' => '%0A'));
    // Формируем строчку
    $txt .= $field['name'] . ": " . $field['value']."%0A";
}

// Отправляем в телеграм сообщение
fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}&disable_web_page_preview=true","r");}
```

Код работает превосходно но есть одно НО. Форма собирает список выбранных checkbox'ов и в значении поля я просто получаю просто строку. И мне нужно разделить и отформатировать эту строку. За это отвечает вот этот кусок:

```
strtr ($field['value'], array ('__' => '%0A'));
```

И по неизвестной мне причине я получаю на выходе следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вначале разделять строку на массив функцией explode() и циклом собирать обратно в строку. Результат тот же. В сторонних онлайн компиляторах код отлично работает. В чём может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `strtr` __возвращает результат__. Где ты используешь этот возвращенный результат? Правильно - __нигде__.